# is specifying isRequired in Proptypes should come at last?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I have a simple component, and I'm utilizing `prop-types` package.

to validate an array of objects, I use something like:

```
CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.isRequired.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.isRequired.string,
    })),
};
```

now, Eslint react/require-default-props give me error that `courses` property is optional but does not have a default value, But if `isRequired` comes after `arrayOf` property, the error is gone.

In order to make a prop required, is it required to stipulate `isRequired` property at last? or it is a bug for Eslint react/require-default-prop plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isRequired` should come after the data type  like 
`PropTypes.string.isRequired`  [you can read more here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

in your case

```
CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string,
    })).isRequired
};
```

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't see a mention about this requirement.